# CSVHelper Passing a value to the MapClass

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

In the source CSV the time but not the date is provided in a field. Is there a way to pass the datetime value to the map class so then we could just combine both using the ConvertUsing?

PseudoCode:

```
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<RhodesMoClassMap>("DateTime");

public MoClassMap(DateTime date)
{
Map(m => m.TimeLastTick).ConvertUsing(row =>
            {
               var timePart = row.GetField("Time last tick");
               var combined = date + timePart;
               return combinedDateTime;
            });
}
```

I have seen some questions about this but no examples and the last thread seemed to melt away a few years ago.

Comment: Can you add an example of the CSV?

Comment: ZZZZ,Z Company,7:29:54 PM  < need to add the Date part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new RhodesMoClassMap(date));
```

Comment: I just ran in to similar, but when I add a ctor parameter I get ```System.InvalidOperationException: No public parameterless constructor found.
   at CsvHelper.ReflectionHelper.CreateInstanceDelegate(Type type, Object[] args)
   at CsvHelper.ReflectionHelper.CreateInstanceWithoutContractResolver(Type type, Object[] args)
   at CsvHelper.ReflectionHelper.CreateInstance[T](Object[] args)
   at CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration.RegisterClassMap[TMap]()

```

Comment: @Ian1971 I suspect you're using the templated version of `RegisterClassMap<mytype>(...)`, which does require a parameterless constructor, but doing as @David shows as `RegisterClassMap(...)` works fine, at least on CsvHelper v27